# Regular expression, specific string with symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following regular expression in my data annotation:

```
[RegularExpression(@"test|test2|test3|test4-5", ErrorMessage = "Please select your status.")]
```

I want the value to accept "test4-5", but it doesnt seem to like the dash symbol, how would i make this accept the exact string "test4-5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers seem almost there, what you actually need is:

```
"^(test|test2|test3|test4\-5)$"
```

Note: Brackets to include the whole word to be included in the logical OR and not just the characters around the pipe symbol.  Escaped hyphen.  Caret and dollar symbols mark the beginning and end of the string.  Giving you an exact match on your allowed strings.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
(test|test2|test3|test4)-5
```

Comment: That would also match "test4" and the hyphen would need escaping too.